# Different character encoding in .net core class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, character-encoding, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing an API and are bumping in to a issue with character encoding. Consider the two following projects in a solution running .NET Core 2.1:

- MyApi.Web
- MyApi.Services

This is the code from my controller in Web

```
[HttpGet("text")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetText()
{
    string culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;
    string encoding = Encoding.Default.ToString();

    string controllerText = culture + " " + encoding + " åäö";
    string serviceText = await _slotService.GetText();

    return _responseBuilder.Success("ControllerText: " + 
    controllerText + " ServiceText: " + serviceText);
}
```

This is the code from my service:

```
    public async Task<string> GetText()
    {
        string culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;
        string encoding = Encoding.Default.ToString();
        return culture + " " + encoding + " åäö";
    }
```

When I call this api from postman I get the following result:

```
{
    "message": "ControllerText: sv (SE) 
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed åäö ServiceText: sv 
    (SE) System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed 
    \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd"
}
```

Why would the controller and service give different results for the "åäö" characters? Even though they seem to have the same culture and encoding. It must have something to do with them creating the strings in different projects (web project, and class library).

Comment: File encodings are the same?

Comment: have you checked the code page EncodingInfo.CodePage & save pages with save as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally figured this out.

The issue was with file encodings in Visual Studio. My first file was saved in Unicode while the second file in the service project was saved as ANSI. It seems like you can't set any options in Visual Studio as to what encoding to always save as. This is instead selected from your Windows language settings.

I fixed this with the following steps:

1. Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents` and check "Save document as Unicode when cannot be saved in codepage"
2. Run the following command in your project folder:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem *.cs -Recurse | ForEach-
   $content = $_ | Get-Content
   Set-Content -PassThru $_.Fullname $content -Encoding UTF8 -Force}
   ```
3. Do a search and replace in your soulution for the unicode character replacement character � and swap it for the correct one.

Maybe not an optimal approach but it solved the problem!

Comment: Although this seems to fix the problem, it doesn't in some edge cases. If your file contains a character that is in the system codepage (e.g. cp1252), but not in ASCII, then it will be saved in your codepage, but it will not be understood in other systems that don't support your codepage (in cp1252 example, linux won't parse it)

Comment: So this solves your problem of two projects on the same system producing different output for the same characters. But I ran into a problem, that `£` is saved in `cp1252` even under the VS setting you mention, but it is garbled on linux